# Different length sum on numpy array axis

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose to have, a numpy 3D tensor `D` of dimension `r x c x d`, such as:

```
r = 2
c = 3
d = 3    
D = np.array([[[1, 5, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 4, 3]], [[1, 1, 6], [3, 1, 7], [5, 1, 3]]])

array([[[1, 5, 3],
        [1, 2, 5],
        [1, 4, 3]],

       [[1, 1, 6],
        [3, 1, 7],
        [5, 1, 3]]])
```

and a 2D integer matrix `Q` of dimensions `r x c`, such as:

```
Q = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2]])

array([[1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

where every element in Q is less than `d`.

I need to sum the first `Q[r_i][c_i]` element of the third dimension of matrix `D` for every `0 < r_i < r` and `0 < c_i < c`.
The expected results (`Res`) using the example above is a 2D matrix of `r x c` (2x3):

```
Res = np.array([[6, 3, 8], [8, 4, 5]])
array([[6, 3, 8],
       [8, 4, 5]])
```

My actual solution is using a list comprehension looping over `r_i` and `c_i`:

```
r = 2
c = 3
res = np.array([[np.sum(D[r_i, c_i, :Q[r_i, c_i]+1]) for c_i in range(c)] for r_i in range(r)])
```

There is a more efficient or elegant solution to solve this problem?

Comment: `(D * (np.arange(d) <= Q[:,None].swapaxes(1,2))).sum(-1)`, IIUC.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try:

```
# this is equivalent to double loop on r_i, c_i
x,y = np.ogrid[:r, :c]

# we take the cumsum on the last axis, 
# then extract the Q[r_i, c_i]'th sum at r_i, c_i
out = D.cumsum(axis=-1)[x,y, Q]
```

Output:

```
array([[6, 3, 8],
       [8, 4, 9]])
```

Cross check

```
np.allclose(out, res)
# True
```